# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::pullCache()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a trouble with laravel i don't know where i have problem, when i try to logout actual user i get the throw name :

> "Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::pullCache()"

I paste the schema:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('avatar');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And the photos schema:

```
Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('desc');
        $table->string('uri');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The web routes:

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/navbar', function () {
    return view('navbar');
});

Route::get('/search', function () {
    return view('search');
});

Route::get('/showUserById/{id?}', 'UserController@showUserById');

// Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@filter');

Route::get('/users', 'UserController@show');

Route::resource('photos','PhotoController');

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);


Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

And the view:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
        {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
           onclick="event.preventDefault();
                         document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
            {{ __('Logout') }}
        </a>
        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            @csrf
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

And the end exception was throwed:

> BadMethodCallException
>   Call to undefined method App\User::pullCache()

Comment: Can you share your logout code?

Comment: i Use laravel out of the box Authorization but i can share it

Comment: Yes please share it.

Comment: `Route::get('/users', 'UserController@show');` logout function is present in UserController or not? Can you share that code please?

Comment: I dont implement logout code i use laravel php artisan make:auth
command to use it on the project